# Is the AVl rotation operation I wrote correct?

Tags: avl-tree

left_right_rotate that I wrote

```
struct Node*left_right(struct Node *x){
    struct Node*a=x->left;
    struct Node*b=a->right;
    struct Node*c=b->right;
    struct Node*d=b->left;
    b->left=a;
    b->right=x;
    x->left=d;
    a->right=c;
    b->height=max(height(b->left),height(b->right))+1;
    x->height=max(height(x->left),height(x->right))+1;
    return b;
}
```

struct below

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
    int height;
};
```

AVL that I read before

```
if (balance < -1 && key < node->right->data) {
    node->right = rightRotate(node->right);
    return leftRotate(node);
}
```

My way of writing is brute,rotate in place directly.The  way I read right_rotate firstly,then left_rotate.Did I write is right?